# will I be able to use windows 7 64bit on my new motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

I have purchased a new motherboard which supports UEFI. Windows 7 is *fairly* new(not the newest,but not old either) so I figured I'd be able to install it once my hard disk arrives.
however, it occurred to me that there may be a problem booting from such a board. 
can I use windows 7 OEM x64 on this?

additional information:
AMD A8 APU
MSI motherboard

Comment: did you research this at all?

Answer (score 2):

Win-7 supports UEFI, and you can always(AFAIK) disable in it in the BIOS of consumer motherboards anyway.